# undefined method `commentable' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> (accesing commentable id and type via polymorphic association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to fix this issue for a day but cannot find solution.

What I am doing now is to render the comment form

```
<%= form_for @comment, remote: true do |form|%>
  <%= form.hidden_field :question_id, value: @question.id%>
  <%= form.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value => @question.comments.commentable.id %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value => @question.comments.commentable.class.name %>
<% end %>
```

I just dont know how to access the commetable_id and type that was created with the comment controller to record the id of the comment and the type of the commenting model (e.g. client or lawyer)

```
  # GET /questions/1 or /questions/1.json
  def show
    set_question
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
```

```
  # GET /questions/1 or /questions/1.json
  def show
    set_question
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
```

```
  resources :questions do
    resources :comments do
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't call `commentable` on `@question.comments` - an association. Pass an array to the `form_for` method with the commentable (`Question`) object and the comment object. You don't need to set any hidden fields.

```
<%= form_for [@question, @comment] do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :content %></div>
  <div><%= f.text_area :content %></div>
  <div><%= f.submit 'Post' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Replace `content` with the field where you're storing the comment's content.

This should generate a `form` tag with an `action` attribute of `/questions/1/comments` which upon submission is processed by `CommentsController#create`.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Comment created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    # e.g. request.path => '/questions/1/comments'
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2] # ['questions', '1']
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

In the `set_commentable` method, the commentable type and its id are detected from the request path. Since `resource` is `'questions'`, `resource.singularize.classify.constantize` returns the `Question` model. The commentable object is then found using the [`find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method. The `CommentsController#create` method creates the comment and redirects to the commentable object which is the question show page (`/questions/:id`). If there's an error, it renders the `new` view (you have to create `views/comments/new.html.erb` to render the form with errors).

Answer (score 1):

You are using question.comments which indicates has many relation, So it will return you an active record association array, So if you want to find the commentable id, you need to take single record from the array. For example if you want first comment commentable id, then use

```
   @question.comments.first.commentable.id
```

If each comment has different commentable id, you need to iterate through loop.

If you have some factor to apply condition, then apply the condition

```
   @question.comments.where('your condition').first.commentable.id
```

If you use above code, still you will get the array, so I have used .first. Use a uniq value in where condition, so you will have only single record with that value.

Comment: Appreciate your answer sir!